# Making animation overlay views

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

i have a problem. I want to add animation to my game board when updating positions after swiping a row on the board. i have made it to the point where i can start an animation at the right point. But there's a catch. When the translate animation starts, it seems like the animation is confined within the tile(button) or just don't show over another button, but i want it to look like it is moving.
This is what happens:
[image]

This is what i want to happen:
[image]

How i start the animations:

```
    Animation tile_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.tile_up);
    //This was a valid move. Add to moves and enable undo for this
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            buttons[x][i].startAnimation(tile_up);
        }
```

Animation (res/anim/tile_up.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shareInterpolator="true"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="100"/>
```

Do anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, finally after 6-7 hours of searching through the internet i finally found the answer i was looking for. Since my layout is made up of nested LinearLayouts, I had to add a

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

attribute to all my LinearLayouts(button parents).

Seems like the issue was the linear layouts didn't want to let it's childs outside to play. Which is understandable, and they're great parents none the less. But i had to make them let go. (Joking here)